# How can I change the html img element source witch dart?

Tags: html, dart, web, dart-webui

I have this img element in my HTML project:

```
<img id="themeToggle" src="./images/moon.svg">
```

and i want to change the source of this element to be "./images/sun.svg".

I tried with:

```
void main() {
    var themeToggleButton = querySelector('#themeToggle');
    themeToggleButton?.onClick.listen((event) {
        themeToggleButton.dataset['src'] = './images/sun.svg';
    });
}
```

since the .dataset attribute is the only one that lets you to access the selected element's attributes, but it does not work. Any suggestion, please?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [.attributes getter](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-html/Element/attributes.html) to get the attributes Map and set there the value:

```dart
themeToggleButton?.attributes['src'] = './images/sun.svg'
```

Note: [.dataset](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-html/Element/dataset.html) (as specified in the docs) is used only for the element properties that start with `data-`